# Cannot preview in Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, preview, anko

I have this problem:
[image]

The error:

```
C:\Users\avi12\OneDrive\Documents\AndroidApps\WhatsApp Easy Sticker Maker\app\src\main\java\com\avi12\whatsappeasystickermaker\MainActivity.kt: (20, 13): Overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun ViewManager.textView(init: (@AnkoViewDslMarker TextView).() -> Unit): TextView defined in org.jetbrains.anko
public inline fun ViewManager.textView(init: (@AnkoViewDslMarker TextView).() -> Unit): TextView defined in org.jetbrains.anko
```

My code, as I just started discovering Anko:

```
package com.avi12.whatsappeasystickermaker

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.jetbrains.anko.design.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        coordinatorLayout {
            textView {
                text = "Begin by tapping the + button"
            }
            floatingActionButton {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anko version: `0.10.8`
Android Studio version: `3.3`

Answer (score 2):

What seemed to be the problem, is that in `build.gradle` I had:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:$anko_version" // sdk15, sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
}
```

And for some reason, this partly fixed the problem (in terms of a successful build, yet still no preview):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:$anko_version" // sdk15, sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...preview ONLY WORKS IF we define our layout in an external class that implements AnkoComponent interface. Below is how we will modify our activity to define our view in a separate class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    MainActivityUI().setContentView(this)
}

class MainActivityUI : AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>) = with(ui) {
        verticalLayout {
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            padding = dip(20)

            textView {
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                text = "Enter your request"
                textColor = Color.BLACK
                textSize = 24f
            }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
                margin = dip(20)
            }

            val name = editText {
                hint = "What is your name?"
            }

            editText {
                hint = "What is your message?"
                lines = 3
            }

            button("Enter") {
                onClick {
                    toast( "Hey ${name.text}! Thank you for contacting us. We will get in touch with you soon.")
                }
            }.lparams(dip(280), sp(80))

        }
    }
}
```

}

I hope it solves the problem, I'll find out shortly...